# How to get country name from longitudes and latitudes in AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, reverse-geocoding, geonames

What is the simplest way to get the country name from longitudes and latitudes. I have been looking on the internet and I did find an ANE but it's not free. I need a very simple way, I don't need any other features. It can be online or offline. 
Another API I found is Geonames API but I can't seem to find out how to use it in AS3 to just get the country name by providing the longitudes and latitudes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As there's no built-in way to do this in AIR, you'll have to use some other API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned in your question, you can use the [findNearby Geonames's WebService](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby) which you can use to load the data ( XML or JSON ) via an [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) object :

```
var lat:Number = 37.26801,
    lng:Number = -115.80031;

var url:String = 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng + '&username=demo';

var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var url_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    url_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_DataLoad);
    url_loader.load(url_request);

function on_DataLoad(e:Event): void 
{
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(xml.geoname.countryName);         // gives : United States
}
```

The XML data returned by that request :

```
<geonames>
    <geoname>
        <toponymName>Groom Lake</toponymName>
        <name>Groom Lake</name>
        <lat>37.26801</lat>
        <lng>-115.80031</lng>
        <geonameId>5505124</geonameId>
        <countryCode>US</countryCode>
        <countryName>United States</countryName>
        <fcl>H</fcl>
        <fcode>LK</fcode>
        <distance>0.07718</distance>
    </geoname>
</geonames>
```

For this code, I used the demo account available to test the Geonames's WebServices, but you should create your own account to use it.

You can also use the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) after [getting a key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) :

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE';
```

then

```
// ...

function on_DataLoad(e:Event): void 
{
    var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    trace(xml.result[0].address_component.(type[0] == 'country').long_name);        // gives : United States
}
```

Where the XML content was :

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>route</type>
        <formatted_address>Unnamed Road, Nevada, United States</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
            <!-- ... -->
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <!-- ... -->
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <!-- ... -->
        </address_component>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>United States</long_name>
            <short_name>US</short_name>
            <type>country</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <geometry>
            <!-- ... -->
        </geometry>
        <place_id>
            <!-- ... -->
        </place_id>
    </result>
    <!--        
        ...        
    -->
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Hope that can help.